# speeding up php/mysql query/correct usage of joins?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, query-optimization

I'm having some issues with some mysql queries taking around 50 seconds to execute some times, but other times its around 1 second. The query does what I need it do but obviously is too slow.

Below are the three tables that are used and showing some of the columns:

products Table (14315 rows)

```
id    | title  | image | price | rrp   | upsell
20381 | test   | test  | 24.00 | 30.00 | 1
```

product_to_category Table (26283 rows)

```
ptc_id | product_id | category_id
33797  | 20381      | 29
```

category_description Table (29 rows)

```
category_id | name     | url_slug
29          | Kitchens | kitchen-products
```

seo_slugs Table (14898 rows)

```
seo_slug_id | route         | seo_slug
26987       | product=20381 | test-product-kitchen-area-2000-500
```

Below is the current codeigniter functions I am using.

```
public function getUpsells() {
$this->db->select('products.id, products.title, products.image, products.category, products.price, products.rrp', FALSE);
$this->db->from('product_to_category');
$this->db->join('products', 'products.id = product_to_category.product_id');
$this->db->join('category_description', 'category_description.category_id = product_to_category.category_id');
$this->db->join('seo_slugs', 'seo_slugs.route = concat(\'product=\', product_to_category.product_id)');
$this->db->where('products.upsell',1);
$this->db->where('products.status',1);
$this->db->group_by('product_to_category.product_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

}
I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction and advise where I'm going wrong. It is to be honest the first time i've used joins in a query and although it seems to work, it is generally very slow when first loading the page, then if refreshed etc it seems to load fairly quick.

Below is the query it runs:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.image, products.category, products.price, products.rrp
FROM `product_to_category`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_to_category`.`product_id`
JOIN `category_description` ON `category_description`.`category_id` = `product_to_category`.`category_id`
JOIN `seo_slugs` ON `seo_slugs`.`route` = concat('product=', product_to_category.product_id)
WHERE `products`.`upsell` = 1
AND `products`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `product_to_category`.`product_id`
```

Profiling result:

```
Starting    18 µs
Waiting For Query Cache Lock    5 µs
Checking Query Cache For Query  48 µs
Checking Permissions    5 µs
Checking Permissions    4 µs
Checking Permissions    4 µs
Checking Permissions    5 µs
Opening Tables  20 µs
System Lock 9 µs
Waiting For Query Cache Lock    15 µs
Init    25 µs
Optimizing  13 µs
Statistics  23 µs
Preparing   19 µs
Creating Tmp Table  21 µs
Executing   5 µs
Copying To Tmp Table    51.8 s
Sorting Result  26 µs
Sending Data    24 µs
End 9 µs
Removing Tmp Table  33 µs
End 7 µs
Query End   7 µs
Closing Tables  14 µs
Freeing Items   12 µs
Waiting For Query Cache Lock    6 µs
Freeing Items   11 µs
Waiting For Query Cache Lock    7 µs
Freeing Items   7 µs
Storing Result In Query Cache   162 µs
Logging Slow Query  6 µs
Logging Slow Query  38 µs
Cleaning Up 7 µs
```

EXPLAIN Result:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |        table         |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |                         ref                         | rows  |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seo_slugs            | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                | 14958 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product_to_category  | ALL    | category_id   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                | 26343 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | category_description | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | wilsonar_hcsupplies.product_to_category.category_id |     1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | PRIMARY | 4       | wilsonar_hcsupplies.product_to_category.product_id  |     1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the query with *qualified* column names.  We don't now your data, so we don't know where the columns are combing from.

Comment: do you have indexes set? How about using a view? One thing for sure: using concat is usually quite slow.

Comment: show us the EXPLAIN of your query

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: I suspect you have not given us the real query -- where does "products.category" come from?

Answer (score 0):

EXPLAIN tells us that product_to_category has an index that MySQL considers using, since possible_keys is "category_id". However, it is not used for some reason.

"rows" is 26343 and "key" is NULL, which means MySQL will have to scan all 
26343 rows in product_to_category for each product, which is going to be horrendous even using the join buffer optimization.

```
product_to_category Table (26283 rows)
ptc_id | product_id | category_id
33797  | 20381      | 29
```

ptc_id is useless, since the primary key of this table should be (category_id, product_id) with a UNIQUE index on (product_id, category_id) added to optimize searches. This makes me suspicious of the database structure, therefore I am going to bet that the designer used the wrong type (ie, anything except INT) for one of the columns in one of the tables. So, check your column types for tinyint, smallint, bigint, unsigned, whatever...

Other causes would be that the index named category_id does not actually index the column category_id. You never know. Please check.

Now, there is another issue with the query, namely that the GROUP BY makes the entire query useless. I wonder what this query is supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

(I have yet to see a useful "Profile".)

Even without seeing the table structure of `product_to_category`, I suspect it is the deficient part.

- Get rid if `ptc_id`
- Change to `PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category_id)`
- Also have `INDEX(category_id, product_id)`

[*Further discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) of the optimal many:many mapping table.

Also, have `INDEX(upsell, status)`.  This composite index may or may not be used, depending on the cardinality of those columns.  If useful, it will be quite beneficial.  If not, then a table scan is necessary.

And get rid of the last two join()s -- you don't use those table.  MySQL is joining to the to make sure they exist, but wasting time in doing so.

Once you get rid of the two unnecessary tables, you can get rid of the `GROUP BY`.

But, then why touch `categories` at all?  Getting rid of that, gets rid of `products_to_categories`.

So this is all you needed is the above index, plus

```
SELECT id, title, image, category, price, rrp
FROM `products`
WHERE `upsell` = 1
  AND `status` = 1
```

But, wait!  That won't work because there is not a `products.category`.

Why sometimes fast?  You have the "Query cache" turned on.  When you run the *identical* query a second time before *any* changes to *any* of the relevant tables, it will be fetched from the QC, usually in a millisecond or so.